# How to create hyperlink in custom view...?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

How to create hyperlink in custom view..
i have created nsview, that contain three hyperlink, but in my case it will call method not any weblink

Comment: So you basically want a button that calls an instance/class method that looks like an html hyperlink?

Comment: yes mark, i want button  that look like hyperlink & call method , it should have same functionality as hyperlink ,

Comment: I removed the Cocoa Touch tag since you said `NSView`. Cocoa Touch is for iOS and uses `UIView`. `NSView` is used in plain Cocoa for OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subclass NSTextField.

Make its background see through by setting it's backgroundColor property to NSColor.clearColor.

Use a Tracking Area to monitor when the mouse is over it so you can change its color:

```
NSTrackingArea* pTrackingArea= [[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:NSTrackingActiveAlways | NSTrackingMouseMoved | NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited owner:self userInfo:nil];
[self addTrackingArea:pTrackingArea];
```

Tracking Area's call certain mouse action methods for you. In this case:

```
-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
-(void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

Set the textColor property of your NSTextField sublclass in these.

To determine when the user clicks, use:

```
-(void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
```

and call whatever method you want from this.